# Creating single build for windows 8 and 10

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, microsoft-metro, winjs

We have developed winjs metro app for windows 8.
Now we did the changes in UI accourding to windows 10.
Code base is same but still we have to create two different builds for windows 8 and windows 10.
Is there any way to create only one build which will work on both the OS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to create only one build which will work on both the OS.

You could create the build for window 8. And it will be upward compatible with window 10.

> Now we did the changes in UI accourding to windows 10.

If you want to fit new UI for windows 10, you could detect current runtime environment and use new UI within window 8 project.

However, if you realize the feature via windows 10 api, you will not use it within windows 8 project. You need to create build for each OS.